# "The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure" System.Data.Common.DbCommand nuance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005, datareader

This could be an sql server database setup issue, but I am not to sure where to start looking.

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aStoredProcedure
@dteSince DATETIME = null
AS
...
```

The C# code to call the stored procedure is:

```
using (IDataReader dr = database.ExecuteReader("aStoredProcedure"))
{
...
```

The C# code works fine on the **Production** environment. Here, **dteSince** will be set to null as it is not supplied as a input parameter.

Problem is when I run this in the **UAT** environment, it returns the message shown in the title - *wrong number of parameters...*

I can fix this by changing the code to:

```
using (IDataReader dr = database.ExecuteReader (CommandType.StoredProcedure, "aStoredProcedure"))
{
...
```

The fix just masks the real problem as to how can the code fails on one environment and works fine on another.

I have dropped and recreated the stored procedure, with no luck.

Technologies used C# 2.0 & Sql Server 2005.

Comment: Related: [The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917145/the-number-of-parameters-does-not-match-number-of-values-for-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3):

IMHO the CommandType should always be specified anyway - explicitness is always preferable to implicitness. It is obvious that something is happening under the hood that is different in both environments but when you are explicit about the command type the code works as expected.

The only thing I can think of - are the database settings exactly the same -particularly in the treatment of NULL's?

**EDIT**

May be worth checking `SET ANSI_NULLS ON/OFF` and `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` ON/OFF - you can look at the properties of both databases and see if the setting match.

Comment: Agree with you regarding the explicitness. I was trying to avoid a code change until we resolve the real issue. It could be to do with the optional input param (NULLS). I'll see what I can find in that area. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Checked the ANSI_NULLS and CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL and they are the same.  I nearly thought this was the issue.  Looks like the c# code change is the only route.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the troubleshooting tips I usually try.

1. Check the assembly **version** of DAL assembly that "database" object type resides in.
2. Check library **reference** to your DAL - Whether you are referencing the DLL from GAC or not  - I had trouble before with DLL referencing **GAC**, which contained old assembly
3. Check your **default database** when your code tries to connect to database in UAT environment - It might be pointing to other databases depending on how you are connected to database.

And all's still not well, clean and **Re**build solution

side comment: Beh, I don't think "System.Data.IDataReader" is to be included in technology used ;)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll take the namespace out. I'll go through your checklist

Comment: Doing a clean and rebuild helped sort this out for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Profiler to see what is happening on the SQL Server perspective.

Ideally getting someone to capture a trace from production as well so they can be compared.